# Declare a struct pointer object/variable as an extern

Tags: c, struct, extern

I intent to declare on object as an extern, but ended up with several `undefined reference to struct object`

Here are the codes

gvars.h

```
#include <structsource.h> //houses the struct definition of newType

extern struct newType *myvars;
```

main.c

```
#include <structsource.h>
#include "gvars.h"

int main(int x){
    struct newType *myvars = myvalue;
    return 0;
}
```

other.c

```
#include <structsource.h>
#include <others.h> //houses definition of others_func();
#include "gvars.h"

int otherfunc(){
    others_func(myvars);
}
```

This is how it works. In the main, the structure variable `myvars` is populated with `myvalue`. Then I want to make it available to other c files as well.

What is the proper way of declaring struct pointer as an extern?

Comment: an `int` is not a pointer either, and the argument**s** to `main` do not match the one you've given... etc... you should get much more diagnostics besides the `undefined reference`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I corrected the main argument already, by the way, the `myvalue` is a valid value for the newType data type.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: That is not a helpful comment, and it is presented in a manner people consider off-putting or rude. It is not helpful because learning about scope is insufficient to answer the problem—truly understanding how to provide an external definition requires understanding linkage and the rules about what makes declarations external and what makes something a definition rather than a declaration. Those rules are not straightforward, not presented in the C standard in a direct way, and are not resolved solely by learning about scope.

Comment: `int main(int x)` is not a proper declaration of `main`. For portable programs, it should be `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main(int myvalue){
  struct newType *myvars = myvalue;
  return 0;
}
```

*myvars* is a local variable, not a global one

but

```
extern struct newType *myvars;
```

says the gloval var *myvars* exists etc

Because this is false and there is no defined global var *myvars* while it is used in *otherfunc()*, the link doesn't find it and says it is undefined

---

You can put the definition of *myvars* outside *main* to be a global var, but may be initialize it inside *main*

```
struct newType *myvars;

int main(int myvalue){
   myvars = ...; // myvalue is an int, to do myvars = myvalue has no sense
  return 0;
}
```

Additional remark : probably you make a mistake about the argument(s) the *main* function receive and it is not like you expect

Comment: Hi, bruno, so how do you suggest is the best way to assign the value for `myvars` so that I would not get undefined reference in in `others.c`

Comment: You still didn't tell how to fix it.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala ok I edited the code to add a possible solution

Comment: @DominicGuana the simpler way is to make _myvars_ global, see the new version of my answer

Comment: @bruno, hi, I corrected the main part. It compiles now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The statement `extern struct newType *myvars;` declares `myvars` to be an identifier with external linkage.

When `struct newType *myvars = myvalue;` appears **inside** a function, it declares `myvars` to be an identifier with no linkage. Because it has no linkage, it will not be linked to the earlier declaration. (This declaration of `myvars` is also a definition because it causes an object to be created.)

Nowhere in your program is there a definition of `myvars` that has external linkage, so the first declaration is never linked to a definition.

To create a definition of `myvars` with external linkage, you must put `struct newType *myvars = myvalue;` **outside** of a function.

Answer (score 1):

You need yo make your pointer global.

```
// this is wrong as myvars is only exists in the main function scope
// and when you call any other function from main it stops to be accesible
int main(){
    struct newType *myvars = myvalue;
    /* .... */
}
```

---

```
// Now it is global and can be used from other functions / compilation units

// you can initilaze this way if the myvalue is a contant expression
struct newType *myvars = myvalue;

int main(){
    /* .... */
}
```

---

If the `myvalue` is not a constant expression you need to initialize it inside te function body (for example `main`)

```
struct newType *myvars;

int main(){
    myvars = myvalue;
    /* .... */
}
```

---

`main` has a very specific arguments they are called `argc` and `argv`